# RF/IR Generation

Tags: rf

I have a project where I'd like to generate GHz to THz frequencies (THz being infrared, of course).

My phone (Pixel 2) operates using at least some of these frequencies.  Is there a way or an app to generate (say) a 1 GHz sinusoidal tone to see on my oscope?  Or an IR tone I could detect optically?

Comment: Do you have an oscope whith a >> 1 GHz bandwith??? You can  likely use your phone's camera to see IR (check with a TV remote).

Comment: Looks you have really misunderstood the concepts you are using here...

Comment: Umm... no.  Your phone can't do this.

Comment: Actually, yeah it can... your phone gets hot, which produces IR.  And your phone is a phone, so it produces GHz.  But controlling these things for a certain (undefined) application?  Not so much.

Comment: GHz carrier is not a tone but modulation can be.

Comment: um, we typically speak of the "Terahertz gap", which is what lies between microwaves and infrared, so your "of course infrared" seems off already. The rest of your question makes not much sense, either – how does your oscilloscope even come into play? I'm voting to close this as unclear and recommend going back and researching what electromagnetic waves really are.

Comment: Cheap IR sources (aside from simple thermal sources) are typically 100's of THz. The 0.5 - 100 THz (aka "far IR") frequency range is a lot more difficult to generate.

Comment: Sorry, I'm forgetting the 10 um CO2 laser line, at about 30 THz. That's widely available. But between ~500 GHz and 30 THz, you're looking at some fairly esoteric technologies to make a source (quantum cascade lasers, for example).

Comment: an electrical arc produces frequencies that go pretty high

Answer (score 1):

- RF: The RF hardware/firmware in cell phones cannot be used to generate arbitrary or unmodulated signals, only to communicate using a defined protocol.
- IR: Most phones do not have infrared transmitters, but [some models do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_with_IR_blaster#Smartphones). You will need to find or write software to command it to turn on. Most IR remote control signals are modulated (toggled on and off) at 38 kHz in addition to the actual digital code — you might find this to be a non-optional feature of the transmitter. I don't know.

If you do want a simple unmodulated IR signal, then obtaining a plain IR LED and a suitable power source is likely to the most convenient way to go.

For RF, there are the problems that

- Use of radio frequencies is regulated. It's still possible to legally use low-power signals for experimental or any other purposes, but you need to read about what you can and can't do and choose a suitable frequency.
- Most RF is modulated in some way, so you'll be paying for capabilities in your transmitter you don't need.

It would probably be best to ask your question question giving much more detail about what your goal is, rather than just "generate a signal". RF and IR are very different.

Comment: Your first point sidesteps the fact that essentially any device that has passed RF regulatory certification has the capability to generate an unmodulated carrier, as that is part of the test process. However that won't normally be exposed to the end user and could require software that won't ship to consumers.